# Hot to get the status of a Windows service in ASP / .net?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I need to find a way to monitor the status of a list of Windows services over HTTP, preferably without any third party program).

All I really need to be able to do is display the service name and its status ('Started' / 'Stopped').

I'm not an ASP programmer so this is a little outside my realm.  I've searched and haven't been able to find much yet.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ServiceProcess;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

        Response.Write("List of running services : <BR>");
        foreach (ServiceController service in services)
        {


            Response.Write(string.Format(" Service Name: {0} , status {1} <BR>", service.ServiceName, service.Status.ToString()));



        }
    }
}
```

just remember to add the system.serviceprocess reference

Comment: What if the website uses Impersonation and ServiceController.GetServices() return Acces Denied? How can the website access this method? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you wish to enumerate services on a *REMOTE* computer. This can be accomplished using WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation), here's how:

```
ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
connection.Username = userNameBox.Text;
connection.Password = passwordBox.Text;
connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query= new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"); 

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
     Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
     Console.WriteLine("Win32_Service instance");
     Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
     Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
     Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
     Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
     Console.WriteLine("PathName: {0}", queryObj["PathName"]);
     Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", queryObj["State"]);
     Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", queryObj["Status"]);
}
```

This code is taken directly from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337(VS.80).aspx), Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "sc query service_name";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```